# primeng how to inline style checkbox?

Tags: html, primeng, primeng-checkbox

How can I use the `style` input of `p-checkbox` to change the border and background color of a checkbox?
I already tried `[style]="{'background': '#ff0000'}"`. But this only applies the style to the div which holds the actual checkbox. So its useless. Instead I need to change the `border-color` and `background` of the div which has the classes `p-checkbox-box` and `p-highlight`.
Note: I cant use CSS here because the colors are dynamic and dependant on the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use renderer2 to manipulate DOM elements and then add style:

1. Get all checkboxes using `document.getElementsByClassName('p-checkbox-box')`
2. Iterate over each element and add the style you want using `renderer2.setStyle()`

try this piece of code and add it in `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
  let chkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('p-checkbox-box')
    for (let index = 0; index < chkboxes.length; index++) {
      const element = chkboxes[index];
      this._renderer2.setStyle(element,'background-color','#bf2222');
      this._renderer2.setStyle(element,'border-color','#bf2222');
    }
```